# Auto completing classes' methods in Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, configuration, ide, sublimetext3

When I'm working in some IDE like Visual Studio I define include and lib folders from a certain SDK so when I edit my sources VS auto instantiates SDK classes' methods showing expected arguments that I have to put in. The question is: is it possible to setup Sublime Text 3 so I could get something similar, i.e. when I typing some method (after including needed headers) I can see the whole method with all arguments which I have to put in)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of plugins for Sublime Text 3 that do what you want. They vary in the setup complexity and in design. I guess the best known are YouCompleteMe and RTags.

However, I urge you to try [EasyClangComplete](https://github.com/niosus/EasyClangComplete) as an easy to setup alternative. I have spent last 6-7 months polishing this plugin to work out of the box. Please give it a try.

I also actively develop it and try to close issues that arise fast.